# How to get the prediction with all reconstructed features from MOJO (GLRM)?

Tags: java, r, h2o, mojo

First I have data (`hex_glrm`) that contains 4938 columns (features) to fit the model. After fitting, I download and save the model in MOJO format to the folder `tmp`.

**script.R**

```
...
model_glrm <- tryCatch({
  h2o.glrm(hex_glrm,
           cols = names(hex_glrm),
           model_id = "model_glrm",
           transform = "STANDARDIZE",
           loss = "Huber",
           regularization_x = "NonNegative",
           regularization_y = "UnitOneSparse",
           k = 100,
           seed = 2017,
           gamma_x = 0.2,
           gamma_y = 0.2,
           init = "Random",
           svd_method = "GramSVD",
           impute_original = TRUE,
           max_runtime_secs = 1200)
}, error = function(err) {
  flog.error(err)
  NULL
})

if (!is.null(model_glrm)) {
  flog.info(" - GLRM model is fitted!")

  # Download generated MOJO
  h2o.download_mojo(model_glrm, path = "/tmp", get_genmodel_jar = TRUE)
}
...
```

Then I create `EasyPredictModelWrapper` and load `model_glrm.zip`. After that I get new user data for prediction and fill it within `RowData`. Then I get the prediction (`drmp`) and create the json for response.

**PredictionServlet.java**

```
...
// Get the MOJO model and the prediction
EasyPredictModelWrapper model = new EasyPredictModelWrapper(MojoModel.load("tmp/model_glrm.zip"));
RowData row = getRowDataFromJson(json); // New data for prediction (4938 features)
DimReductionModelPrediction drmp = model.predictDimReduction(row);

// Create the json response 
JsonObject json = new JsonObject();       
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (double i : drmp.dimensions) {
      builder.append(i);
      builder.append(", ");
}
json.addProperty("recommendations", builder.toString());
json.addProperty("size", drmp.dimensions.length);    

// Emit the prediction to the servlet response
response.getWriter().write(json.toString());
response.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
...
```

**response.json**

{
"recommendations":"1.2323, 2.3423, ...",
"size":100
}

But when I get the prediction `drmp.dimensions` contains only 100 values. How to get the prediction with all reconstructed features (4938)?